# "Like the others" vs "Unlike others"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, vocabulary

Ok. So the situation is say, most people I come across hate Justin Bieber but I don't.

Then what should I say to state this fact?

> 1. I don't hate Bieber like everyone else.
> 2. I don't hate Bieber unlike everyone else.

Or could they maybe both work:

> 1. I do not hate Bieber  (*the way*) **like** everyone else (*does*).
> 2. I do not hate Bieber (*which is*) **unlike** everyone else.

Meaning the same things in different wording.

Comment: The comma is your friend: _"I don't hate Bieber, unlike everyone else."_ ... _"I do not hate Bieber, unlike everyone else."_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Like everyone else, I don't hate Bieber.

means that everyone else does not hate Justin Bieber, and you agree with them.

> Unike everyone else, I don't hate Bieber.

means the opposite, that everyone hates Justin Bieber, and you *disagree* with them.

> I don't hate Bieber the way everyone else does.

implies that while everyone hates Justin Bieber, you also hate him but *in a different way*.  Or it could be that you don't hate him.  We'd have to figure out the meaning from context.

Comment: Is it necessary to put the **like/unlike** part at the beginning,as you have done in your answer or the way I wrote it were also correct ?

Comment: @user118494 - I don't think it's _required_ to put it at the beginning, but I think there is less ambiguity with the sentence structured that way. The way you wrote it – _I don't hate Bieber like everyone else_ – one might assume that means _I don't hate Bieber the way I hate everyone else_.

Comment: @user118494 it's more about my personal preference than grammar.  I think putting the "like" phrase at the beginning is clearer and more logical.  But it's fine to say "I don't hate Bieber like everyone else".